# Gulp, Vue, Webpack, Babel and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, vue.js, vue-component

I've been trying whole day to get it to work without any luck so if someone could shine some light that would be very much appreciated.

I'm trying to set up environment for working with ES6 files as well as Vue using Webpack.

I've installed all dependencies, and created the following files:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {

    entry: './resources/assets/source/js/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    webpack    = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('script', () => {

    "use strict";

    return gulp.src('./resources/assets/source/js/app.js')
               .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/js/'));

});

gulp.task('default', ['script']);
```

**resources/assets/source/js/app.js**

```
var Vue = require('vue');

import Alert from './components/Alert.vue';

new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    components: { Alert },

    ready() {
        alert('ready');
    }

});
```

**resources/assets/source/js/components/Alert.vue**

```
<template>

    <div :class="alertClasses" v-show="show">
        <slot></slot>
        <span class="Alert__close" @click="show == false">x</span>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        props: ['type'],

        data() {
            return {
                show: true
            };
        },

        computed: {

            alertClasses() {

                var type = this.type;

                return {
                    'Alert': true,
                    'Alert--Success': type == 'success',
                    'Alert--Error': type == 'error'
                };

            }

        }
    };

</script>
```

When I rung `gulp` everything is bundled and compiled, but when I run it in the browser I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` pointing to the line within the `resources/assets/source/js/app.js` file.

After hours of trying to figure out what might be causing it I've run out of ideas and am on the verge of giving up so would appreciate any help.

Comment: Which version are you using for Babel and Webpack?

Comment: Its webpack-stream@3.2.0 and babel-loader@6.2.7

Comment: Try removing the quotes from `'/\.(js|vue)$/'` - it might be parsed as a string at the moment when you want it as a regex.

Comment: Thanks @Aurora0001 - this definitely is the first good step :). Now when I run gulp I get error saying "Error: ./resources/assets/source/js/components/Alert.vue
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0) pointing to the <template> tag

Comment: Use the [vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) for `.vue` files instead of Babel by adding another element to the list of `loaders` in the `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: I've now updated the loader, but now I get `Unexpected token export` after successful compilation.

Comment: Can you update the post with your latest config?

Comment: Yes - just did - I didn't notice - the message is now actually pointing to the `export` within the `Alert.vue`: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`

Comment: Now, when I'm compiling with gulp I also get `[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/Users/sebastian/Code/vue-test/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".` - any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove query object from your webpack.config.js file, and create .babelrc file, that would contain this stuff.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "comments": false
}
```

Comment: It also works fine without `transform-runtime` - thanks @Belmin

Answer (score 0):

`import` issue seems to be solved in the comments above but there's one more.

`.vue` files do not seem to be written in standard JavaScript syntax. In order to import them, we need to somehow transform them to JavaScript.

While looking at the `webpack.config.js` you might notice, that files with `.vue` extension do not get transpiled in any way.

You can solve this problem with custom loaders. In this case, the loader you're looking for is [`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/)

Steps to solve the issue:

- `npm install --save-dev vue-loader`
- once done, try updating your `webpack.config.js` with following `module` section:

`module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue'
        },
    ],
}`

More details:

- http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/index.html

Does it help in any way? If not, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Maciej - I'm afraid this didn't resolve it. Should the loader be `vue` or `vue-loader` ?

Comment: Hi @seb, please try once again. I didn't strip the unnecessary apostrophes in the loader tests, the code is now updated.

Comment: Yes - I have it exactly as in your example, but without any luck I'm afraid.

Comment: Should be `vue`, but if things don't work, give `vue-loader` a try. If no success, please paste the errors you're receiving for `vue` as a loader. Maybe there's a bit of useful information in them.

Comment: I tried both, but it actually doesn't make any difference - in terminal I only get this `[BABEL]` warning mentioned above and files are compiled - however still with the `export` issue when viewing in the browser.

Comment: Here's a sample `webpack.config.js` file that uses `vue-loader` : https://github.com/BrokingClub/CDN/blob/a0ac36d6419cf0738e6691b119a29f4931259719/webpack.config.js and a sample `.vue` component: https://github.com/BrokingClub/CDN/blob/a0ac36d6419cf0738e6691b119a29f4931259719/src/main/resources/assets/js/components/Navbar.vue so you can compare your setup

Comment: Yeah - updated code accordingly, however still without any luck.

Comment: If we're bundling files with webpack, there should be no explicit `export` calls being made in the transpiled file. They should be all transformed. Are you sure you point to the output file rather than input file in your HTML? Can you please change your `filename` in the webpack config to something else, e.g. `bundle.js` and try to load that file in the HTML? Did anything change?

Comment: Are you have installed babel-transform-runtime ? Try with removing the query obj from webpack and create .babelrc file, with this structure `{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "comments": false
}` Also you packages.json file could help ;)

Comment: @MaciejSmoliński - it points to the correct file - I double checked.

Comment: Thanks @Belmin - this did the trick! It worked without the `transform-runtime`. By removing `query` block from the `babel` loader and adding the `.babelrc` with the preset worked a charm. @Belmin could you add it as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: Thanks both for your help - really appreciate it.

Comment: @seb could you possibly create a github gist containing the code from the output file? Might help further investigation. Also, is your example available somewhere so we can play with it and check what's wrong?

Comment: No need for the gist then. Congratulations resolving the issue. Good luck writing Vue.js components @seb!

Comment: Thanks @MaciejSmoliński !