# Unexpected Token identifier with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I installed Vue via npm and wanted to use it. Now when I load my page I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import in main.js:1

It worked when I put it the link to vue CDN in my HTML code, but now that I installed via NPM I receive this error.

**Update**
I find it strange that it does not work with any import at all. Even my custom components. As soon as I use the import statement, I get this error.

The Vue File:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import Form from './core/Form';

window.Vue = Vue;
window.axios = axios;
window.Form = Form;

window.Event = new class {
    constructor() {
        this.vue = new Vue();
    }

    fire(event, data = null) {
         this.vue.$emit(event, data);
    }

    listen(event, callback) {
        this.vue.$on(event, callback);
    }
};

Vue.component('panel', {
    template: `
            <div :class="panelType">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <slot name="header"></slot>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <slot></slot>
                 </div>
            </div>
`,
    props: {
        name: { required: true }
    },

    computed: {
        panelType: function() {
            switch(this.name) {
                case 'default': return 'panel panel-default';
                case 'primary': return 'panel panel-primary';
            }
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('tabs', {
    template: `
                    <div>
                        <div class="tabs-container">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li v-for="tab in tabs" :class="{'tab-pane active': tab.isActive }">
                                <a :href="tab.href" @click="selectTab(tab)">{{ tab.name }}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <slot></slot>
                        </div>
                    </div>
`,
    data() {
        return { tabs: [] };
    },

    created() {
        this.tabs = this.$children;
    },

    methods: {
        selectTab(selectedTab) {
            this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
                tab.isActive = (tab.name == selectedTab.name);
            })
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('tab', {
   template: `
        <div v-show="isActive"><slot></slot></div>
`,
    props: {
        name: { required: true },
        selected: { default: false }
    },

    data() {
       return {
           isActive: false
       }
    },

    mounted() {
       this.isActive = this.selected;
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    components: {
        Example
    },

    data: {
        form: new Form({
            incidentReference: '',
            streetName: '',
            latitude: '',
            longitude: '',
            featureTypeId: 1,
            archived: 0,
        }),
        incidents: []
    },

    computed: {
        href() {
            return '#' + this.name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
        }
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.getIncidents();
    },

    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            this.form.post('/api/v1/incidents');
        },

        getIncidents: function() {
            console.log('getIncidents');
            var self = this;
            axios.get('/api/v1/incidents').then(function(response) {
                // set data on vm
                console.log(response.data);
                var incidentsReceived = response.data.data.map(function (incident) {
                    return incident;
                });
                Vue.set(self, 'incidents', incidentsReceived);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you are using `window.vue = vue;` 
rather than 
`window.Vue = vue;`

OR

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

Comment: Unfortunately didnt work. When I change to this, I receive: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: This might help, If you look near the bottom of the page Evan has answered some queries about import problems. [link](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:N18hlgE7pYcJ:https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/300/how-to-require-inside-a-vue-file/7+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didnt help. Hm.. it is so strange. A direct import in HTML script form works

Comment: Hmm, Take a look at this answer and see if it helps, Vue files look like they need to be transformed to JS so using Webpack should convert them. [Maybe Related Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408527/gulp-vue-webpack-babel-and-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Comment: I actually use gulp which converts as it should. As long as I use the direct <script> tag in the HTML to import Vue, everything goes smoothley

Comment: Probably a silly question but just checking, you are adding script tags to your Vue file.